# Conversion from string "MM/yyyy" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, vba, date, datetime

Here is code, any thoughst how to clear up my error?

```
Public Function AddNextMonthDue(ByRef OldNMD As String, ByRef MonthsToAdd As String) As String
    Dim dOldNMD As Date
    Dim dNewNMD As Date
    Dim sOldNMD As String
    If Len(OldNMD) = 4 Then ' MMDD format
        sOldNMD = "20" & Right(OldNMD, 2) & Left(OldNMD, 2) & "01"
    Else
        sOldNMD = OldNMD ' YYYYMMDD format
    End If
    dOldNMD = CDate(Mid(sOldNMD, 5, 2) & "/1/" & Left(sOldNMD, 4))     
            dNewNMD = DateAdd(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Month, CShort(MonthsToAdd),dOldNMD)
    AddNextMonthDue = Format(CDate(dNewNMD), "MMyy")

End Function
```

Comment: Why are you passing MonthsToAdd as a string?  If you need a Short, then pass in a Short.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can spot two potential issues:

On line:

```
sOldNMD = "20" & Right(OldNMD, 2) & Left(OldNMD, 2) & "01"
```

If you are really parsing a MMDD date as your comment says, you are winding up with your date in the format: 20DDMM01, which I don't think is what you intend, because the second line of the 'if' statement is keeping the original YYYYMMDD format.  In the first 'if' branch, I don't see how you are going to obtain a YY fragment from your input string unless you default to a particular year (YY) value.

So the first branch of the 'if' is reformatting to an invalid date format.

**UPDATE 1: Oops, the following is is a mistake on my part: Ignore the part about Mid being zero-based.**
Also, in your line:

```
CDate(Mid(sOldNMD, 5, 2) & "/1/" & Left(sOldNMD, 4))
```

I *believe* Mid assumes a 0-base index in .NET, so you are trying to extract the MM portion at the second position of your MM fragment, not the first.

Try
    CDate(Mid(sOldNMD, 4, 2) & "/1/" & Left(sOldNMD, 4))
instead.

**UPDATE 2: This still stands, from what I can tell:**

But I think you need to address that first branch of your 'if' statement first.

All that said, I am inferring a lot of your intentions based on the code/comments.  I could be totally off the mark.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. This function is causing me an error: Conversion from string "MM/yyyy" to type 'Date' is not valid. I am working on converting this code from VB to Vb.Net.  This function will determine the next next month due.

Comment: What is the value of the *OldNMD* input parameter?